# Do not wait for page to finish loading for integration test

Tags: selenium, rspec, phantomjs, capybara

I have a long loading page (lots of images) and I just want to test as soon as the first element I need appeared. I don't want to wait until every element finished loading. How can I do that?

Snippets of my current code:

```
visit ...

expect(page).to have_selector('#block .item', minimum: 1)
```

Driver config:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
  client.timeout = 360

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, :http_client => client)
end
```

Comment: You can try adapt to your needs this example of waiting for a certain element to become visible: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js

Comment: @Vaviloff I'm not really sure how to do that as `wait_until` has been removed and this one is in js (my code is in ruby using capybara selectors).

Answer (score 0):

1) You can try with the `within` method: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FSession%3Awithin

This way, Capybara will not analyze the DOM from the beginning to the end, but just the part of code you include in the within method.

Let's say you want to click a `button` inside of a `div`. In this example i will use the xpath but it depends on your **Capybara.default_selector**

```
 within(:xpath, 'THE XPATH OF YOUR DIV') do
  click_button('YOUR BUTTON')
 end
```

2) Another option is to skip the images loading, setting it in your `Capybara config`.

```
Capybara.register_driver :firefox do |app|
 profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
 profile['webdriver.load.strategy'] = 'unstable'
 Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox, profile: profile)
end
Capybara.default_driver = :firefox
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work (tested) as I don't think the code has passed `visit` line. The `visit` is blocking codes below it.

Comment: are you able to visit the page? what happens next?

Comment: I can visit the page but it's loading too long (too many images) but the element I want to check is already visible.

Comment: I'm not using webkit, I think. I'm not loading any webkit related gem. Among of the gems are `capybara`, `poltergeist`, and `selenium-webdriver`

Comment: what driver are you working with? can you please share your spec_helper?

Comment: is there a reason why you are not using `capybara-webkit` as a driver? in case you want to try it, just `gem install capybara-webkit` and in your spec_helper `Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit`. I also updated the answer, maybe this will work for you as will avoid the full page to load.

Comment: Your example actually still load the images. Does `unstable` is supposed to disable images?

Comment: yes, it should. btw, my recommendation is to use `capybara_webkit`, you have more flexibility and the tests will be faster as it will not have to load a real browser page

Comment: It's an inherited code. I'm trying my best not to change the driver if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue here really is images taking a long time to load you should probably look into [puffing-billy](https://github.com/oesmith/puffing-billy) which provides a programmable proxy that will work with the selenium driver. With that you can set up puffing-billy to return an error for any requests for images you don't care about.  The other option is to swap to a driver that allows for setting an option not to load images.

Comment: I'd say the main issue is here the page is taking too long to load (because of the image). Maybe it'd possible to increase the timeout value. I'm OK increasing it more, the page shouldn't be taking 5 minutes long.